# File Upload angular js with web API on different server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app and I want to upload a file using web api deployed on different server.

Actually I prepared a sample having the html on web api and i was successful uploading the file their, but as soon as i try to upload it from my angular app to different server (cross origin than it fails), I have implemented cross origin support too.

Note: I am making an ajax call fro file upload.

```
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Index</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button1").click(function (evt) {
            var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/WebApi/api/Fileupload/Post",
                    contentType: false,
                    crossorigin: true,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (messages) {
                        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                            alert(messages[i]);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error while invoking the Web API");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- form name and controller declare  -->
<form>
    <span>Select file(s) to upload :</span>
    <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check it out: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Answer (score 2):

I f I am getting the issue right, you are using `Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC WebAPI` . In this case you should use `EnableCORS` option and set it in your `WebAPI config` as below:

Steps:
1. Install Nuget for CORS in package manager console as

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

2. Add `config.EnableCors` in `WebApiConfig`

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
         config.EnableCors();
    }
```

3. Add the EnableCors attribute in your controller as below:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
 public class ValueController : ApiController
```

For more details refer: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is by default a browser security feature which blocks http requests to another web resources

you can change this default behavior if you add the flags `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ; `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in your web application server's response including the allowed origins (resources)

you did not specify the web application software in use (asp.net, django, node.js, ...) but for instance, this is how you support it in [django](https://gist.github.com/barrabinfc/426829)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking on the Internet a long time ago and found a way to upload Angular App on Internet. You need have an account on `Vercel.com` (it's free) then in your project folder of Angular write these commands:

```
1- ng build --prod //Generate the dist folder

2- npm install -g now //install the tool

3- now //in our directory "dist\"

4- Set up and deploy -> Yes

5- Introduce our Vercel account

6- Link proyect -> No

7- Set proyect name //Enter, dont write nothing

8- Override settings -> Yes

9- Choose -> Build Command
```

And finally you will have a link what finish in `.now.sh`.  Open this link from any device in your internet explorer and you will have your app on the internet.

PS: On `vercel.com` you could change DNS, etc. because if you have a domain, you could change your url (`http:/.....now.sh`) to what you want.

This method is tested in Angular 8 and 9 without problems.

This is my first post, I hope it would help many people.